# Pandas: How to aggregate multiple columns?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

How can I create a function that takes two columns as input and outputs a score; specifically, the [earth mover's distance](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.wasserstein_distance.html).

I could not find the documentation on how it is achievable through groupby?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand what you are trying to accomplish you can `groupby.apply` with `lambda` or create a function and `groupby.apply`:

```
from scipy.stats import wasserstein_distance
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame([np.random.randint(0,10,2),
                   np.random.randint(0,10,2),
                   np.random.randint(0,10,2),
                   np.random.randint(0,10,2)], columns=list('AB'))

df['C'] = list('AABB')

# use apply with lambda function
print(df.groupby('C').apply(lambda df: wasserstein_distance(df['A'], df['B'])))
```